# How to update all sub-sub tag of XML with different values using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, xml, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

lets say this is my XML

```
<sky class="new">
<list name="school">
<p>63</p>
<p>62</p>
<p>61</p>
</list>
</sky>
```

And this is my values in list.

```
value = [51,56,87]
```

Now I what I need is:

```
<sky class="new">
<list name="school">
<p>51</p>
<p>56</p>
<p>87</p>
</list>
</sky>
```

So far this is what I did:

```
for i in soup.find_all('sky', {'class':'new'}):
        k = i.find('list',{'name':'school'})
```

After this I am not getting what to do, could you help here?

EDIT1:

```
<sky class="new">
    <list name="alpha">
<item>
    <p unit="kg">63</p>
    <p weight="wg">54</p>
</item>
<item>
    <p unit="kg">57</p>
    <p weight="wg">32</p>
    
</item>
</list>
    </sky>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another version:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<sky class="new">
<list name="school">
<p>63</p>
<p>62</p>
<p>61</p>
</list>
</sky>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'xml')
values = [51, 56, 87]

for p, new_value in zip(soup.select('sky.new > list[name="school"] > p'), values):
    p.string = str(new_value)

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sky class="new">
<list name="school">
<p>51</p>
<p>56</p>
<p>87</p>
</list>
</sky>
```

Comment: Why you left <sky class="new">, actually we have many such tags with different class name for exampl <sky class="aplha">,<sky class="beta">, etc and I want to do this only when class="new".

Comment: @AkashRathor You can do `'sky.new > list[name="school"] > p'`. See my edit.

Comment: Actually instead of 'html parser' i were using 'xml' parser, I forgot to update that and with xml parser it is not working what can we do here ?

Comment: @AkashRathor When I replace `html.parser` with `xml`, it's working (see my edit). You can also parse `xml` with `html.parser`. If you still get the error, I think it's somewhere else.

Comment: Finally it worked for me too Thanks for your Solutions and explanations.

Comment: Could you also help at my edit 1 , I am not getting to make a pattern for it.

Comment: @AkashRathor `sky.new > list[name="school"] > p` is CSS selector. It will select all `<p>` tags under `<list name="school">` tags which are under `<sky class="new">` class

Comment: Thanks for explaining but I was asking for my EDIT1.

Comment: @AkashRathor Your XML is malformed: See where the first `<item>` and `<list>` are opened and where's closed. They are crossed.

Comment: @AkashRathor To get all `<p>` tags you can do `sky.new > list[name="alpha"] > item > p`

Comment: @AkashRathor Then you can do `sky.new > list[name="alpha"] > item > p[unit="kg"]`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
targets = soup.select('p')
for target in targets:
    repl = str(value[targets.index(target)])
    target.string.replace_with(repl)

soup
```

Output:

```
<html><body><sky class="new">
<list name="school">
<p>51</p>
<p>56</p>
<p>87</p>
</list>
</sky></body></html>
```